# Playing youtube live stream using permanent URL

Tags: flutter, youtube, media-player

I want to display a live stream from YouTube in Flutter using a permanent URL.

It's very simple if I have the video Id by simply using [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) as follows:

```
YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
  initialVideoId: 'NpEaa2P7qZI',
  params: YoutubePlayerParams(
    showControls: true,
    showFullscreenButton: true,
  ),
);
```

However, I want to display videos from permanent URLs like on of these:

- https://www.youtube.com/user/NASAtelevision/live
- https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCLA_DiR1FfKNvjuUpBHmylQ

The reason being that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA9UZF-SZoQ where the id is `nA9UZF-SZoQ` (the current live stream url) is not always valid and the app will break if it changes.

Is there as solution to play permanent URLs from youtube in flutter? Do I have to use the youtube api for this or maybe look for an iframe solution instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a [pull request](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/pull/550) at the github repo. If its merged, it will be as simple as:

```
YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
  initialVideoId: 'placeholder-will-be-ignored',
  channelId: 'YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID',
  params: YoutubePlayerParams(
    showControls: true,
    showFullscreenButton: true,
  ),
);
```

Comment: It doesn’t work. It shows "This live stream recording is not available

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter check this also.

Comment: i'm using the `youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.0` but still there aren't a property called `channelId` can you advice?

Comment: @DehanWjiesekara - The pull request wasn't merged yet. You can fork your own version, build it locally then use it when compiling the app if you absolutely want to use this package.